# Can ClearML (formerly Trains) work a local server?

Tags: trains, clearml

I am trying to start my way with [ClearML](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml) (formerly known as Trains).

I see on the [documentation](https://allegro.ai/clearml/docs/rst/getting_started/index.html) that I need to have server running, either on the ClearML platform itself, or on a remote machine using AWS etc.

I would really like to bypass this restriction and run experiments on my local machine, not connecting to any remote destination.

According to [this](https://allegro.ai/clearml/docs/rst/deploying_clearml/index.html) I can install the `trains-server` on any remote machine, so in theory I should also be able to install it on my local machine, but it still requires me to have Kubernetes or Docker, but I am not using any of them.

Anyone had any luck using ClearML (or Trains, I think it's still quite the same API and all) on a local server?

- My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: (There's a [difference between formerly and formally](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/formerly-formally/).) (Check title(s), too.)

Comment: @greybeard corrected my spelling 10x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team (formerly Trains)

> I would really like to bypass this restriction and run experiments on my local machine, not connecting to any remote destination.

A few options:

1. The Clearml Free trier offers free hosting for your experiments, these experiment are only accessible to you, unless you specifically want to share them among your colleagues. This is probably the easiest way to [get started](https://app.community.clear.ml).
2. Install the ClearML-Server basically all you need is docker installed and you should be fine. There are full instructions [here](https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/deploying_clearml/clearml_server_linux_mac/) , this is the summary:

```bash
echo "vm.max_map_count=262144" > /tmp/99-trains.conf
sudo mv /tmp/99-trains.conf /etc/sysctl.d/99-trains.conf
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sudo service docker restart

sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/data/elastic_7
sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/data/mongo/db
sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/data/mongo/configdb
sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/data/redis
sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/logs
sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/config
sudo mkdir -p /opt/trains/data/fileserver

sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allegroai/trains-server/master/docker-compose.yml -o /opt/trains/docker-compose.yml
docker-compose -f /opt/trains/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

3. ClearML also supports full offline mode (i.e. no outside connection is made). Once your experiment completes, you can manually import the run to your server (either self hosted or free tier server)

```py
from clearml import Task
Task.set_offline(True)
task = Task.init(project_name='examples', task_name='offline mode experiment')
```

When the process ends you will get a link to a zip file containing the output of the entire offline session:

```
ClearML Task: Offline session stored in /home/user/.clearml/cache/offline/offline-2d061bb57d9e408a9420c4fe81e26ad0.zip
```

Later you can import the session with:

```py
from clearml import Task
Task.import_offline_session('/home/user/.clearml/cache/offline/offline-2d061bb57d9e408a9420c4fe81e26ad0.zip')
```

Comment: Can we host on local and not on live ? Os: Windows 11

Comment: (disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team) 
If you mean the ClearML Server, than yes, it can be hosted on a local machine using docker-compose (the clearml-server GitHub repository contains a docker-compose-win10.yml file which I believe will work with Windows 11 as well)

Comment: Thanx for informing. Docker on Windows is really pain. Have to switch to Linux.